# Select script tags from jQuery get response

Tags: jquery

When I try to select script tag content from a jQuery get response, I get nothing. I want to insert the content inside the script tag into another div in the dom. This is what I'm trying:

```
jQuery.get("http://some.url"), function(data) {
    var scriptDivs = jQuery(data).find("#scriptdiv");
    var scriptOutput = jQuery("#scriptoutput");
    jQuery(scriptDivs).each(function(index) {
        jQuery(scriptOutput).append(jQuery(this).html());
    });
});
```

I change the script tag to a div and boom, everything works. I know jQuery does weird things with script tags, but all the solutions I've tried after hours of searching haven't worked. What am I missing?

Comment: There's a misplaced ")" in that, you know - right after the url in the "get" call.

Comment: Also you should post what the "data" actually looks like.

Comment: Wait, you're using the '#' id selector here -- could you not just do $("data").find("script"); ??? Or is the '#scriptdiv' just an example?

Answer (score 0):

About getting the content within the -tag. This approach works fine:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="myScript">
function hello() {

}

function world() {

}
</script>
<script >
    alert($('#myScript').html());

</script>
```